# Amazon ECS MissingAuthenticationTokenException

Tags: amazon-web-services

I follow this instruction http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html
and here's what I got:

```
$ aws ecs list-clusters

{
    "clusterArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxx:cluster/MyCluster", 
        "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxx:cluster/default"
    ]
}
```

and on the EC2 instance:

```
$ cat /var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log

t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=info msg="Starting Agent" module=main stack=    [agent/agent.go:32]
t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=info msg="Loading configuration" module=main stack=[agent/agent.go:34]
t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=info msg="Connecting to docker daemon" module=main stack=[agent/agent.go:41]
t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=info msg="Connected to docker daemon" module=main stack=[agent/agent.go:43]
t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=info msg="Registering Instance with ECS" module=main stack=[agent/agent.go:50]
t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=crit msg="Could not register" module="api client" err="{\"__type\":\"MissingAuthenticationTokenException\",\"message\":\"Missing Authentication Token\"}" stack="[github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/agent/api/api_client.go:175 agent/agent.go:51]"
t=2015-02-02T18:31:45+0000 lvl=eror msg="Error registering" module=main err="{\"__type\":\"MissingAuthenticationTokenException\",\"message\":\"Missing Authentication Token\"}" stack=[agent/agent.go:53]


cat /var/log/ecs/ecs-init.log

ecs-init [Mon Feb  2 18:31:43 UTC 2015]: pre-start
ecs-init [Mon Feb  2 18:31:43 UTC 2015]: Loading Amazon EC2 Container Service Agent from file /var/cache/ecs/ecs-agent.tar
ecs-init [Mon Feb  2 18:31:44 UTC 2015]: start
ecs-init [Mon Feb  2 18:31:44 UTC 2015]: Starting Amazon EC2 Container Service Agent
ecs-init [Mon Feb  2 18:31:45 UTC 2015]: Exited 1
```

So where Authentication Token should be set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication tokens should be set by the IAM role that you use to launch your container instance.

Did you set up an IAM role for Amazon ECS with this procedure: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ecs.html#create-an-iam-role

Also, you need to launch your container instance with that IAM role.

Hope this helps.